# filter-mapping dispatcher tag error

Tags: java, tomcat, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am trying to use leverage browser caching for my web css, js  files. I was following this http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Expires_Filter , which says to add-

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
 <init-param>
 <param-name>ExpiresByType image</param-name>
 <param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
 <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
 <param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
<param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
<param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
...
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

in web.xml. But inside `filter-mapping` tag `dispatcher` tag showing error

```
The content of element type "filter-mapping" must match "(filter-name,(url-pattern|servlet-name))".
```

which means I think that content inside filter-mapping should be only `filter-name` and `url-pattern|servlet-name`. I also tried [urlRewriter](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#filterparams) also as suggested in answer [configuring  Tomcat for leveraging browser caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207515/configuring-tomcat-for-leveraging-browser-caching) but stukc in same problem. Please someone explain this.