# How to enable GZIP in my tomcat server having Https/ssl

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have added below the code in my Tomcat /server.xml for enable the gzip but not work

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
           compression="on" 
     compressionMinSize="2048" 
     noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
     compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml"/>
```

This work me for locally but not on my WEB SERVER i.e tomcat server having Https/SSL protocol

Any buddies can help me ?

Thanks in advance for replying.

Comment: Which tomcat version you use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use same configuration for SSL port also its basically port 8443,edit you server.xml near SSL port like below. first you need to uncomment this line

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
        maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
        sslProtocol="TLS" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048"
        noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
        compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml"/>
```

Comment: can you suggest for Browser  Leverage  for same tomcat configuration ?

Comment: can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207515/configuring-tomcat-for-leveraging-browser-caching

Comment: I was try this code but it create an error please tell me where to embed the code in Tomcat /web.xml  and I was posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349055/how-to-enable-the-browser-cache-for-tomcat-8-0-14-having-https-ssl?