# How to enable the browser cache for Tomcat 8.0.14 having Https/SSL

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have added the following code in Tomcat /web.xml

```
<filter>
<filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresByType image</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 2 weeks</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 2 weeks</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 2 weeks</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

And following code added in Tomcat /context.xml

```
<context cachingallowed="true" crosscontext="true" debug="5"
     path="/jasperserver-pro" reloadable="false">
<valve classname="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator"
       disableproxycaching="false" securepageswithpragma="true">

</valve>
</context>
```

This code working for locally but on WEB SERVER having Https/SSL.
Any buddies can help me ?

Thanks in advance for replying.

Comment: Which web-browsers did you test?

Comment: Crome Web Browser..

Comment: i am facing similar issue, was there any resolution for this?